# pass data to edit from the controller to the view in a many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, eloquent, inertiajs

Hi everyone i have a many-to-many relationship between the `turnos` table and the `dias` table like this:

[image: database schema]

Currently, I'm doing the CRUD of the `turnos` table and for each `turnos` I have to assign many `dias`, I did it with the attach method.

Now the issue is in the `edit` method... how am I gonna get the assigned `dias` that is related to that `turno` so I can pass it to the view and the user can edit it?

If someone knows it please help me, I would appreciate it very much

```php
//Dias Model
public function turnos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Turno::class);
}

//Turnos Model
public function dias()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Dia::class);
}

// Controller
public function edit(Turno $turno)
{
    // $dias = ??
    return Inertia::render('Turnos/Editar', [
        'turno' => $turno,
        'dias' => ??
    ]);
}
```

The edit view Should looks like this:

[image: form]

Comment: If Turnos "hasMany" dias relationship is well done, you could access dias using `$turno->dias` to get them all.

Comment: @Guille is right. You can access all the "dias" linked to your "turno" with `$turno->dias`, and you don't need to return "dias" data collection - just access it inside your view with your "turno" data collection. In addition, you might consider eager loading your relationship also.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the relation with the load() method and just return the $turno variable that will contain the "turno" and the "dias".

```
public function edit(Turno $turno) {
    $turno->load('dias');

    return Inertia::render('Turnos/Editar', [
        'turno' => $turno
    ]);
}
```

On the client side you can use v-model to fill your inputs.